# Laravel Breeze and Laravel Sanctum how to safely mix authorizations?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I have a mobile application that uses Laravel REST API. Authorization in this application uses Laravel Sanctum Package. This architecture works great, but I needed to create not only a mobile application but also a website. Since I have complex business logic on some pages of the site, I won’t be able to use pure PHP, I’ll have to use a javascript and a framework such as Vue. Already have a REST api for working with data, but the problem is authorization. A question about security, how correct is this approach and whether it is possible to mix `Laravel Breeze` auth and `Laravel Sanctum`. My idea is that when registering a user, I would also create an access token for him, but store it not on the client browser, but pass it through the view. Since I'm new to the Laravel architecture, perhaps there are better solutions to this problem?

```
//controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
 
if (Auth::check()) {
    $url = "/api/product/url-for-auth-user"
    $token = $userAccessTokenFromDb;
}else{
    $url = "/api/product/url-for-anonymous-user"; 
    $token = "";
}


//blade webpage
  <div id="app">
        
            <div>
                //Vue component to which the link to REST API and token are passed
                <product url="{{$url}}"  token="{{$token}}"></product>
            </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you can create a new route in `web.php` to retrieve the token, since Breeze uses session to authenticate, your XHR request from vue will pass the authenticate and be able to get the token eventually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all works great if you use the intended features, use the web.php and api.php in routes for Breeze. When you log in a user with api also set the session cookie, and vice versa. I've moved away from breeze for a while does it not use Sanctum like JetStream? JetSream uses sanctum for sure anyway:

```
    Middlewares = [
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),//which is AuthenticateSession::class
   ]
```

You set in config/auth.php the different gaurds for web and api
return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
   
],
```

in config/sanctup you can define that web gaurd as the default:

```
   'guard' => ['web'],
```

This should all already be set for you!
Then you can just use the middleware in web.php for web that uses sanctum, and routes/api.php should be used for routes, that is where you define the authorization routes:

//routes/web.php
Route::middleware([
'auth:sanctum',
])->group(function () {

```
    //protected routes
   

});



//api.php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

breaze already creates this in web.php, it all works with minimal effort out of the box I can't think of what needs to be set manually if you are doing it right, I think you just need to use the routes seperate and use middlewears and install sanctum and breeze with breeze first per the laravel installation documentation.